# Puzzling security issue with SharePoint 2010 Central Admin authentication on Windows 7

Tags: authentication, central-administration, windows-7

I have a really odd issue with SharePoint 2010 central admin on Windows 7 (x64 if that matters).

Somehow when I go to Central Admin and hit any of the _admin links I get a password prompt. I looked at the web.config in question which is located under %commonprogramfiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\ADMIN and the groups allowed there are basically the local Administrators (BUILTIN\Administrators) and the WSS_ADMIN_WPG group (MACHINENAME\WSS_ADMIN_WPG), of which I am both a member (and yes I logged out and back in after adding myself and restarted IIS for good measure).

The login works as soon as I add an entry  to the list but the login does not work otherwise (result being continued prompts for username/password).

Anyone ever encounter this issue and have a clue what could be going on here?

Any help greatly appreciated

Mirko

Answer (score 3):

You should run the Central Admin link from the Start menu As Administrator, as well as use the DisableLoopbackCheck (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861).

Answer (score 1):

OK,

a bit weird that I am answering my own question, but oh well. Apparently in Windows 7 you have to disable UAC in order to get this to work.

If someone knows of a better way please let me know regardless, but my problem is resolved by turning this off.

In addition to now being able to access the pages above it was also not possible to add/extend/delete web apps.

Hope this helps someone (or better I still hope someone has a better answer than to turn UAC off).

Mirko